# $12$ women and $10$ men are on the faculty. How many ways are there to pick a committee of $6$?

Tags: combinatorics

$12$ women and $10$ men are on the faculty. How many ways are there to pick a committee of $6$?

This is a question on an old hw that I am trying to understand. Part c of the question states

(c) at least one man and one woman must be chosen

I am confused as to why I can't do $C(20,4)$. This is not the answer. The answer is $$C(22,6) - C(12,6) - C(10,6)$$ I understand why this answer makes sense but I just want to know why $C(20,4)$ doesn't work by just removing a single woman and man from the group?

Comment: If there were $2$ men, $2$ women and a committee of $2$, your logic would give $\binom22=1$ possible committees. Is that right?

Comment: What you are missing here is that there are multiple ways to pick the woman and man who were predetermined and you are not considering in your equation

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The committee has to be of size 6. there are 22 people in total and I thought I could just remove a women and a man that leaves 20 people left and 4 positions left.

Comment: @JohnLou Do do have any idea how I could account for that in my equation?

Comment: I would hazard that it should be $12*10*C(20, 4)$, which would account for variations in the first two people. EDIT: and according to your answer, I'm wrong. Sorry about that. Combinatorics is not my forte.

Comment: @JohnLou I tried that and it comes out way too big compared to the correct answer.

Comment: $C(20,4)$ is not a factor of the right answer, so the method that you are using must have more terms. This would make it more complicated, so I suggest you stick with what they gave. Also, notice how the equation that I presented earlier doesn't account for when we select the two people on the outside. Because order DOESN'T matter, selecting them in the beginning is incorrect, I think.

Comment: @JohnLou say you exclude Albert and Alice and then you come up with the selection Bernard, Beatrice, Charlie, Cathy and David. You could come up with the same selection if you had excluded Edward and Elisabeth instead. In other words, by computing  $12\cdot10\cdot C(20,4)$ you are double counting some of the possible selections.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify:

$\binom{22}{6}$ includes the following combinations:

$(6m, 0w),(5m, 1w), (4m, 2w), (3m, 3w), (2m, 4w), (1m, 5w), (0m, 6w)$

Since the question has the words "at least", We need to subtract the number of ways in which the first and the last of the above terms can be chosen which are

$\binom{12}{6}$ and $\binom{10}{6}$ respectively.

And if you want to see where the overcounting occurs in $12*10*\binom{20}{4}$

$= 12*10*(\binom{11}{4} + \binom{11}{3}\binom{9}{1} + \binom{11}{2}\binom{9}{2} + \binom{11}{1}\binom{9}{3} + \binom{9}{4})$.

Look at the first term. $12*10*\binom{11}{4}$ which should count number of ways of choosing $5$ men and $1$ woman and exceeds the actual $\binom{12}{5}\binom{10}{1}$ by a factor of $5$

Answer (score 0):

It won't let me comment since I'm below 50 rep.

$C(20,4)$ won't work because the combination only looks at 4 spots.

I did it a little longer way

$\binom{10}{5}\binom{12}{1}  +\binom{10}{4}\binom{12}{2} +\binom{10}{3}\binom{12}{3}+ \binom{10}{2}\binom{12}{4} +\binom{10}{1}\binom{12}{5} = 73,479$

Answer (score 0):

The number $\binom{20}{4}$ is the number of ways of selecting a committee of six people that contains a particular man and a particular woman, say Andrew and Abigail.  However, it is possible to form a committee of six people that includes at least one man and at least one woman without Andrew, without Abigail, or without both.